# Bayesian Hierarchical Clustering prior update

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, hierarchical-clustering, dirichlet-process

I am working through Heller and Ghahramani's "Bayesian Hierarchical Clustering" paper ([https://www2.stat.duke.edu/~kheller/bhc.pdf](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Ekheller/bhc.pdf)) and things aren't quite working out the way I expect with regards to the Dirichlet Mixture Model Process priors, so I would appreciate any help.

Particularly, Figure 3 gives the algorithm for computing the prior on the merging of two subtrees:

**initialize** each leaf $i$ to have $d_i = \alpha, \pi_i = 1$
**for** each internal node $k$ **do**
$d_k = \alpha \Gamma(n_k) + d_{left_k} d_{right_k}$
$\pi_k = \frac{\alpha \Gamma(n_k)}{d_k}$
**end for**

Suppose I start by merging points 1 and 2. Then using the algorithm from Figure 3, we have:

$d_{(12)} = \alpha \Gamma(2) + \alpha \cdot \alpha$
$         = \alpha + \alpha^2$
$\pi_{(12)} = \frac{\alpha \Gamma(2)}{\alpha + \alpha^2}$
$          = \frac{1}{1 + \alpha}$

This works out as expected for the Dirichlet process mixture model prior (given in Appendix A). However, suppose we then merge point 3 into the same cluster with points 1 and 2:

$d_{(123)} = \alpha \Gamma(3) + d_{(12)} \cdot d_3 = \alpha \Gamma(3) + (\alpha + \alpha^2) \cdot \alpha = 2 \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3$
$ \pi_{(123)} = \frac{\alpha \Gamma(3)}{2 \alpha + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3} = \frac{2}{2 + \alpha + \alpha^2}$

This doesn't seem to be quite right with respect to the $\alpha$ term because I would expect the prior to be:
$\pi_{(123)} = \frac{1}{\alpha + 1} \cdot \frac{2}{\alpha + 2} = \frac{2}{\alpha^2 + 3\alpha + 2}$

What am I missing?